# Altair: specify a renderer that's enabled by default

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to enable a renderer except for calling `alt.renderers.enable('mimebundle')` in code? So if the user imports altair she doesn't have to perform any additional actions?

For example, in plotly you can set an environment variable `PLOTLY_RENDERER=plotly_mimetype`. Is there something similar in altair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Altair does not currently have any mechanism to specify a renderer aside from calling `alt.renderers.enable`.

But if you are using Jupyter, you could provide an IPython startup script that does this; for example, you can create a file at the path `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/start.py` with the following contents:

```py
import altair
altair.renderers.enable('notebook')
```

and this will be executed at the start of any Jupyter/IPython session.

If you don't wish to import Altair in every session, you could instead define in this file a [Python import hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) that will execute custom code the first time Altair is imported. For example, it might look something like this:

```py
import imp
import os
import sys

class _AltairImportHook(object):
  def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
    if fullname != 'altair':
      return None
    self.module_info = imp.find_module(fullname, path)
    return self

  def load_module(self, fullname):
    """Loads Altair normally and runs pre-initialization code."""
    previously_loaded = fullname in sys.modules
    altair = imp.load_module(fullname, *self.module_info)

    if not previously_loaded:
      try:
        altair.renderers.enable('notebook')
      except:
        pass
    return altair

sys.meta_path = [_AltairImportHook()] + sys.meta_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `alt.renderers.enable('mimebundle')` does not display charts inline.

It can be replaced with:

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('default')
```